# halt while sending email with Poco Net

Tags: c++, smtp, poco-libraries

I'm trying to send an email using the Poco Net library with this code (my credentials are arbitrary obviously):

```
void send_email() {
//   Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession session("localhost", 465);
  const std::string& smtp_host {"mail.example.com"};
  const std::string& smtp_user {"marinos@example.com"};
  const std::string& smtp_passwd {"myPassword"};
  std::string to = "marinos@example.com";
  std::string from = "marinos@example.com";
  std::string subject = "Your first e-mail message sent using Poco Libraries";
  subject = Poco::Net::MailMessage::encodeWord(subject, "UTF-8");
  std::string content = "Well done! You've successfully sent your first message using Poco SMTPClientSession";
  Poco::Net::MailMessage message;
  message.setSender(from);
message.addRecipient(Poco::Net::MailRecipient{Poco::Net::MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT, to});
  message.setSubject(subject);
  message.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
  message.setContent(content, Poco::Net::MailMessage::ENCODING_8BIT);
  try {
    Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession session(smtp_host, 465);
    session.open(); // this is where it halts
    try {
      session.login(Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, smtp_user, smtp_passwd);
      session.sendMessage(message);
      std::cout << "Message successfully sent" << std::endl;
      session.close();
    } catch (Poco::Net::SMTPException& e) {
      std::cerr << e.displayText() << std::endl;
      session.close();
    }
  } catch (Poco::Net::NetException& e) {
    std::cerr << e.displayText() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and my program simply halts. I've used a debugger to locate the problem and it seems that the program halts when calling `session.open()`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not know specification of your SMTP server, I am speculating that you're probably suppose to use SMTPS instead of plain SMTP, because port 465 is default port for SMTPS (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)). I guess the program halts during SSL handshaking. By looking into [Poco documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureSMTPClientSession.html) I see that there exists SSL version of the `Poco::Net::SMTPClientSession`. Thus, you should try with `SecureSMTPClientSession`. Check if your mail server requires START_TLS, in that case I guess you should additionally call `bool startTLS()`.